# Can't access NAS over WiFi

Tags: wireless-networking, router, nas

I have a WD MyCloud NAS wired to my Aztech router, which I must use as it provides IPTV from Singtel.

This is what I can do with with the NAS.  I can:

- access the cloud functionality into the NAS remotely and wirelessly.
- access the NAS via ftp over WiFi.
- ping the device and view its web page over WiFi.
- stream music over WiFi.
- map shares when wired to router.

I cannot:

- map the NAS shares or access its files via windows over WiFi.

It has the same workgroup and gateway details. Its on static IP. I've tried port forwarding and disabling Windows firewalls.

I've tried everything from changing TCPIP adapter settings to disabling QOS.

I cannot access the NAS from any machine over wifi.

Can anyone figure this one out please?

Comment: Did you perhaps disable the SMB client on your WiFi connection? Please include a screenshot of your WiFi connection’s properties ([looks like this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/R68pL.png)).

Comment: You should check if your NAS and your router allow Windows File Sharing over WiFi. You could narrow down the culprit: 1. WiFi for NAS<->router and LAN for router<->PC, 2. LAN for NAS<->router and WiFi for router<->PC.

Comment: Hi,.. I know its not the NAS fault because I do all of the above with another hard drive. None of my other laptops either can see the NAS's over wifi either, so I know it is a router issue. But the router is a terrible Aztech router and I have no choice but to use it. So the question really is, what changes can I make in windows to handle a poor quality router?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,... so I bought a second router and used it as an access point. Lo and Behold I could access my NAS. It turns out the Aztech router (as I suspected) is faulty (or at the very least can't handle network attached storage over wifi). Nothing wrong with my setup, nor the NAS... just that the router just couldn't do it.

But I need this Aztech router to access my IPTV. So looks like I'll be stuck with a dual router & access point set up.

Answer (score 0):

For all late comers to this, like me, the answer to my problem ended up being the Windows public/private classification of the network.

Here's what happened in my office:

- A worker's computer was originally connected via ethernet, but was moved to a location without a jack
- The computer was then re-connected to the network via the available WiFi.
- When they connected to the network Windows prompted them for the type of connection and they chose "Public", which in Windows is the more strict configuration by default.

The "public" designation essentially prevented the machine from seeing anything else attached to the network. By changing the classification of the WiFi connection from "public" to "private" the machine was once again able to mount the NAS (and see everything else it used to see on the network).